# nuget package split-out config from library

Tags: dll, package, nuget, config, nuget-package

Is there any advantage to breaking-out library config-settings files into a separate package ?

Let's say we package-up a lib + config , and then update it :

```
MyLibrary.1.0 package
contents : MyLibrary.dll v1.0 + MyConfig.xml (original)

MyLibrary.1.1 package 
contents : MyLibrary.dll v1.1 + MyConfig.xml (revised)

Project A
subscribe MyLibrary.1.0 package ( MyConfig.xml original ) 

Project B 
subscribe MyLibrary.1.1 package ( MyConfig.xml revised )
```

Alternately we can split-out dll and xml into separate packages :

```
MyLibrary.1.0 package 
contents : MyLibrary.dll v1.0 

MyLibrary.1.1 package 
contents : MyLibrary.dll v1.1 

MyConfig.1.0 package 
contents : MyConfig.xml (original) 

MyConfig.1.1 package 
contents : MyConfig.xml (revised) 

Project A
subscribe MyLibrary.1.0 package
subscribe MyConfig.1.0 package  ( MyConfig.xml original )

Project B 
subscribe MyLibrary.1.1 package 
subscribe MyConfig.1.1 package  ( MyConfig.xml revised )
```

The only advantage I can see is that with configs in separate packages , it's possible to update to latest config without updating to latest library - but it's unlikely that would ever be useful. And we lose the strong-coupling of lib and related config settings.